# xfce4 window manager: increase the width of window borders for growing/shrinking windows

Tags: xfce, window-manager, resize

I use an ultra-wide monitor that has big but not super-huge resolution (2560x1080 I think). One long standing irritation I've had is that getting the mouse cursor over a window border (corner, really) to resize a window is really a pain in the neck. On the native laptop 1080 screen it's also kind-of tricky.

I run xfce4 as my desktop. Is there any way to tell the window manager to increase the "active" window border size to some larger number of pixels?